# Making a piece of code loop back to a certain point in the code if wrong input from user

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN 6



int main()
{
int choice;
int monthd;
int dayd;
int hourd;
int minuted;
int montha;
int daya; 
int houra; 
int minutea;
char flightcode[MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN+1];
char arrival_city [MAX_CITYCODE_LEN+1];
flight_t flights [MAX_NUM_FLIGHTS];
do
{
printf("1. add a flight\n");
printf("2. display all flights to a destination\n");
printf("3. save the flights to the database file\n");
printf("4. load the flights from the database file\n");
printf("5. exit the program\n");
printf("Enter choice (number between 1-5)>\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);

switch (choice)
{
 case (1):
      printf("Enter the flight code: \n");
      scanf("%s",&flightcode[MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN+1]);
      printf("Enter departure info for the flight leaving SYD.\n");
      printf("Enter month, date, hour and minute separated by spaces>\n");
      scanf("%d %d %d %d",monthd,dayd,hourd,minuted);
      continue;
 case (2):
     printf("yay");
      continue;
 case (3):
     printf("Goodbye\n");
     continue;
     default: printf("Wrong Choice. Enter again\n");
                break;
 }

 } while (choice != 3);
 return 0;
 }
```

Within case 1 i need the program to loop back to printf("Enter month, date, hour and minute separated by spaces>\n"); if the user enters nonsense values for scanf("%d %d %d %d",monthd,dayd,hourd,minuted); thanks for any help

Comment: Every single part of `scanf("%s",&flightcode[MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN+1]);` is wrong. `%s` should not be used because it doesn't limit the amount of input (leading to buffer overflows). `&flightcode[MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN+1]` doesn't point to storage where input can be placed; it points one element past the end of the `flightcode` array. Finally, `scanf` should not be used for user input (prefer reading whole lines with `fgets` or similar, then parse them afterwards). If you do use `scanf`, always check its return value.

Comment: ok, so i've now fixed up the scanf and the program is still crashing when i try to input the month, day,hour and minute .

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
  //the stuff in case 1
} while(nonsense);
```

This is what I usually do. The syntax is probably different for you but the idea is that case 1 run once and then repeat as long as there is nonsense. 
Just make this run in your case 1 and change the syntax to your language. Hope it helps!

Comment: case (1):
          printf("Enter the flight code: \n");
          scanf("%s",&flightcode[MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN+1]);
          printf("Enter departure info for the flight leaving SYD.\n");
          do{
          printf("Enter month, date, hour and minute separated by spaces>\n");
          scanf("%d %d %d %d",monthd,dayd,hourd,minuted);
          }while(12<monthd || monthd<0 || 31<dayd || dayd<0 || 
         24<hourd || hourd<0 || 60<minuted || minuted<0);
          continue;

Comment: it crashes whenever i put in an invalid input. Not sure why.

Comment: or even when i put in avalid input

Comment: what language is it? im going to  try and run it myself